# How do I add extension methods in dom elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I have elements I get this way

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('my-element');
```

or

```
    var elems = document.querySelector('.all-elements-with-this-class');
```

what I want to do is this

```
    elem.myExtensionMethod();
```

or

```
    elems.myExtensionMethod();
```

My extension method might, as I have imagined, would be implemented this way

```
    var myExtensionMethod = function() {
        this.classList.add('add-this-class-to-all');
    }
```

How do I do this extending dom elements in javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: you should use `Symbol`s, not regular names to avoid collisions with future extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at adding to the `HTMLElement` and `NodeList` prototypes, respectively.

For example

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.myExtensionMethod = function() {
  this.classList.add('add-this-class-to-all');
}
NodeList.prototype.myExtensionMethod = function() {
  this.forEach(el => el.myExtensionMethod())
}

document.getElementById('p1').myExtensionMethod()
document.querySelectorAll('li').myExtensionMethod();
```

```css
.add-this-class-to-all {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.add-this-class-to-all:after {
  content: " but now it's red!"
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">This is a plain old paragraph</p>

<ul>
<li>List #1</li>
<li>List #2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about compatibility ?

Comment: @Loenix with what? Sorry, your question is unclear

Comment: What about compatibility with browsers ? Are all browsers supporting it ?

Comment: @Loenix as long as they support `Element.classList` and `NodeList.forEach`. Even if they don't, there are pollyfills for both and we'd be talking really old browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Like this, the elements inherit from `Element`

```
Element.prototype.myExtensionMethod = function() {
    console.log("myExtensionMethod!", this);
};
```

Its not recommended because of "browsers" - a better approach is to use some kind of wrapping object that holds a reference to your element, and has the extension methods, that way the elements kan be kept "as is" by the various browsers, and you kan still reference them. Its not as bad as it used to be though